# how to generate regex from a substring，for example

Tags: java, regex

I want to get a regex

condition param :input string and select substring index and regex group name

example1：

param：select substring，and input a group name

```
{
    "logInfo": "<86>Feb 19 2022 14:03:19 idss-03 sshd[767719]: Accepted password for root from 10.11.39.16 port 40658 ssh2",
    "subLogs": [
        {
            "begin": 4,
            "end": 24,
            "name": "time"
        }
    ]
}
```

return：

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "content": {
        "reg": "(?<time>[\w]+\s+[\d]+\s+[\d]+\s+[\\d]+:[\d]+:[\d]+)"
    },
    "message": "success",
    "errorCode": ""
}
```

example2：

param：select multi substring，and input multi group name

```
{
    "logInfo": "<86>Feb 19 2022 14:03:19 idss-03 sshd[767719]: Accepted password for root from 10.11.39.16 port 40658 ssh2",
    "subLogs": [
        {
            "begin": 4,
            "end": 24,
            "name": "time"
        },
        {
            "begin": 96,
            "end": 101,
            "name": "port"
        }
    ]
}
```

return：

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "content": {
        "reg": "(?<time>[\\w]+\\s+[\\d]+\\s+[\\d]+\\s+[\\d]+:[\\d]+:[\\d]+)\\s+[\\w]+-[\\d]+\\s+[\\w]+\\[[\\d]+\\]:\\s+[\\w]+\\s+[\\w]+\\s+[\\w]+\\s+[\\w]+\\s+[\\w]+\\s+[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+\\s+[\\w]+\\s+(?<port>[\\d]+)"
    },
    "message": "success",
    "errorCode": ""
}
```

how can do it ？  use java language， I have no idea how to do it，Can you give me some advice?

Comment: How much variation in the input string should the regex support? Your examples suggest that length variation is to be tolerated, but word separator count is expected to be constant. And by the way, why do your example regexes ignore the `<86>` part of the input string?

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously completely impossible.

Let's say your input string is "2022" as you have in your examples, and you 'want a regex that matches that'.

Okay. Here are some:

- `2022`
- `20+22`
- `21*[0-5]+2*`
- `\d{4}`
- `\d*`
- `\d+`
- `\d{2,}`
- `[0-9]+`
- `[02]{4}`
- `(?i)[0-9]+(?:\\s+AD|BC)`

the list is **literally** endless.

Hence, without some additional input (such as human eyeballs or from a small 'selection'), what you want is **impossible**.

We're entering hard Artificial Intelligence territory: As a human you can look at that lot and go: I know! That's a timestamp! - but you're just making assumptions. It could be a build year + a serial number that unfortunately look exactly like a timestamp. As AI solutions to this tend to be, they'd be:

- **incredibly** complicated, as in years of work.
- they are a heuristic tool: There will always be sequences where the AI tool either has no idea, or takes a wild stab in the dark - and as a consequence, sometimes guesses wrong.

Whatever happened to make you go: I know - I will write a program that figures out the right regex to parse a logline given an arbitrary logline - you went a step too far, because that's not doable. For example, whichever code emits the logline generally knows exactly what it looks like, so perhaps they can contribute the regular expression somehow.

Comment: I understand the OP's question such that the "param" part is given, including the begin/end indexes. So, the task seems a bit easier (the fact is given that from 4 to 24 we find content to be named "time"), but still not trivial.

Answer (score -1):

Agreed on **rzwitserloot** however, there is an online tool.

https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/

The source codes can be found under following repository.

https://github.com/noxone/regex-generator

This may give you the insight to build your own. If you add enough constraints, then you can achive your goal

Comment: OP is clearly showing what they want returned, which is to come up with a regex that matches what is written there. In your code here, the regex `(?<time>...)` is provided by you. Given that it is in the `returns:` section, the question is: How do I generate it from the provided log message.

Comment: I just misunderstood the problem, however OP is not showing it clearly unfortunately. I am updating my answer, thanks for the explanation.